# WebClient.UploadFile pass upload file as stream

Tags: c#-2.0, webclient

I am trying to use WebClient.UploadFile in my project to post file to server. WebClient.UploadFile accept file name uri as parameter but I would like to pass file stream instead of file name uri. Is that possible with WebClient?

Comment: @Thomas What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the methods [`WebClient.OpenWrite`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.openwrite%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and `OpenWriteAsync` to send a stream back to your server.

If you use the later then subscribe to `OpenWriteCompleted` and use `e.Result` as the stream to `CopyTo`.

Answer (score 7):

Here are some examples that shows how to write stream to the specified resource using [WebClient class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.WebClient(v=vs.110).aspx):

Using [`WebClient.OpenWrite`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.openwrite%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
     var fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
     using (var postStream = client.OpenWrite(endpointUrl))
     {
         postStream.Write(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
     }
 }
```

Using [`WebClient.OpenWriteAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.openwriteasync%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
     client.OpenWriteCompleted += (sender, e) =>
     {
        var fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
        using (var postStream = e.Result)
        {
            postStream.Write(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);    
        }
     };
     client.OpenWriteAsync(new Uri(endpointUrl));
 }
```